# Where can I find the proof that retarded integral is the solution of the inhomogeneous wave equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations

Professor Jefimenko proved the "wave field theorem" in his book "Electromagnetic Retardation and Theory of Relativity" in Example 1-2.3. The theorem is as follows. For the inhomogeneous wave equation
$$\nabla^2{\mathbf V}(x,y,z,t)-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2{\mathbf V}(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t^2}={\mathbf Z}(x,y,z,t),$$

if ${\mathbf V}$ vanishes at infinity, the solution can be represented by the retarded integral 
$${\mathbf V}=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\frac{[{\mathbf Z}]}{r}dV^\prime,$$
where "[]" is the retardation symbol such that a function $f(x,y,z,t)$ if being retarded, is  $[f]=f(x^\prime,y^\prime,z^\prime，t_r=t-r/c)$ where $r$ is the distance between the source point $(x^\prime,y^\prime,z^\prime)$ and the field point (or, observation point) $(x,y,z)$, and the integration is with infinitesimal volumes $dV^\prime$ over volume where the source function ${\mathbf Z}$ occupies.

The confusion came to me when he asserted in his proof "Let us now divide the volume of integration in Eq (1-1.2) (the above equation)  into two parts: $vol1$ and $vol2$. Let vol1 be a very small region close to the point of observation, so that within this region the retardation can be neglected. We then have from Eq (1-1.2)
$${\mathbf V}_1=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{vol1}\frac{\mathbf Z}{r}dV^\prime$$
where the integral is not retarded" (There are discussions of ${\mathbf V}_2$ which is irrelevant to my question so I did not quote here). I have difficulty in understanding why "within this region the retardation can be neglected". I ask here where I can find other proofs with similar approach so I can compare them and get a better understanding of this assertion.

I knew the other stachexchange question [Help with the solution to the linearized wave equation known as Retarded Integral](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/287027/help-with-the-solution-to-the-linearized-wave-equation-known-as-retarded-integra) but I thought most textbooks used the Fourier transform approach other than the approach shown above. One example of the Fourier transform approach is http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/jk1/lectures/node7.html .

Update: I found one "Principles of Optics" (7th edition) by Max born and Emil Wolf, page 79, the second paragraph. Preview is available on google books.

Update: I found another one with greater details, in the book "Relativity made relatively easy" by Andrew M. Steane , page 176-180. Preview is available on google books.

Comment: What is the question? To show the validity of your second equation? Your third equation is just the definition of $V_1$. note that you will also have another contribution $V_2$ (that you didn't write).

Comment: @lcv Thanks. My question is "I ask here where I can find other proofs with similar approach". I edited the body of the question to included something about ${\mathbf V}_2$.

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. It should be doable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me write the solution of the inhomogenous wave equation spelling out the parameters dependence. I will write $x,x'$ for the spatial coordinates.

$$
V(x,t) = -\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} dx' \frac{Z(x', t - |x-x'|/c)}{|x-x'|}
$$

Now consider a small ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $x$, $B_\epsilon(x) =\{ x' \in \mathbb{R}^3 : |x-x'|\le\epsilon\}$. You can split the integral over $\mathbb{R}^3$ into the integral over $B_\epsilon(x)$ plus the integral over its complement. The first integral corresponds to $V_1$. Hence

$$
V_1(x,t) = -\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{B_\epsilon(x)} dx' \frac{Z(x', t - |x-x'|/c)}{|x-x'|}
$$

However $|x-x'|<\epsilon$ so let us expand the numerator in $\delta:=|x-x'|/c \le \epsilon/c$. For simplicity let us assume that $Z(x,t)$ is differentiable with continuous derivative in $t$ and that it is continuous in $x$. We get

$$
Z(x', t - |x-x'|/c)=Z(x',t)- \frac{|x-x'|}{c} \partial_t Z(x', \xi).
$$

where $\xi$ is some number between $t-\delta$ and $t$. Note that $\xi$ depends on $x,x'$ and goes to $t$ if $\epsilon \to 0$. 
 Hence

$$
V_1(x,t) = -\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{B_\epsilon(x)} dx' \frac{Z(x', t) }{|x-x'|} + E
$$

where the error $E$ is

$$
E = -\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{B_\epsilon(x)} dx' \frac{ \partial_t Z (x', \xi) }{c}
$$
By assumption $\partial_t Z(x',\xi)$ is continuous in $x'$ and since $B_\epsilon(x)$ is compact it admits a maximum $M =\sup_{x' \in B_\epsilon(x)} |\partial_t Z(x',\xi)|$. Then

\begin{align}
|E| &\le  \frac{1}{4\pi c}  \sup_{x' \in B_\epsilon(x)} |\partial_t Z(x',\xi)| \int_{B_\epsilon(x)} dx' \\
 &= \frac{M}{3} \frac{\epsilon^3}{c}
\end{align}

So we can write 
$$
V_1(x,t) = -\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{B_\epsilon(x)} dx' \frac{Z(x', t) }{|x-x'|} + O(\epsilon^3/c)
$$

and the leading term is not retarded.

Comment: There is a small problem. Could you please fix it? It is from $Z=Z(x^\prime,t)+o(\epsilon /c)$ to $V_1(x,t)=\mbox{the target term}+o(\epsilon /c)$. Note that the first small quantity $o(\epsilon /c)$ is divided by another small quantity $|x-x^\prime|$ so how could we justify that the result is the second small quantity $o(\epsilon /c)$? Thanks.

Comment: I was  a bit cavalier, I added some details. Note that I assumed slightly more than previously.

Comment: Thanks. I think it would be better if you explicitly state what $M$ is (in the equation second to the last), and probably "$Z$ is differentiable with continuity in $t$" implies $\partial_t Z(x^\prime, \xi)$ is bounded at $t$.